# ReactJS App Does not return the correct page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am new to ReactJS and is trying to figure it things how to have an app with a different header for the login page and then another header once the user was logged in.

I only want to have the very first page to have the `LoginHeader` and then the `PostHeader` as the main header once they get authenticated.

However, when I am on the my login page, whenever I click the sign in button I automatically get taken to my `PostHeader` page even though I routed my correct link. Everything in the `PostHeader` works fine, like when I click `Home` and `Create` they return the pages they are supposed.

My code is down below

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Switch, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "./_components/header/header";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={createHistory()}>
    <div>
        <Header />
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Header.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link,Route,withRouter, Switch, } from 'react-router-dom';
import PostHeader from './PostHeader';
import LoginHeader from './LoginHeader';

class Header extends Component{
    render(){
        if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
            return(
                <LoginHeader />
            );
        };
        return(
            <PostHeader />
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

LoginHeader.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link,Route,withRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import SignIn from '../signin/signin';
import TopProjects from '../create_projects/top_projects';

class LoginHeader extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div>
                    <h3>The Web App</h3>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><Link to="/sign-in">Sign In?</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="/top-projects">Top Projects</Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignIn}/>
                    <Route path="/top-projects" component={TopProjects} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginHeader;
```

PostHeader.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../home/home';
import CreateProjects from '../create_projects/create_projects';

class PostHeader extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div>
                    <h3>The Web App</h3>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="/create-projects">Create</Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/create-projects" component={CreateProjects} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PostHeader;
```

I just want to have different headers for some pages.

Comment: Why are you using window.location.pathname, rather than the Router for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in your `Header.js`, you are only rendering the `LoginHeader` if you are in the root route.

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
    return(
        <LoginHeader />
    );
};
```

So when you click the sign in button, it redirects you to `/sign-in`, thus  when `Header` is re-rendered, the condition will fall on the `else` statement which returns the `PostHeader`.